# "Go to definition" option doesn't work in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

"Go to definition" option doesn't work in Visual Studio Code. This happens with Python and methods/functions with multiple implementations.

In Pycharm I get a list of options. There is a similar thing in VS Code or a workaround for this? Thanks for your time!

[**VSCode screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZQx4.png)

[**Pycharm screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LesOV.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling methods from an object in the function argument, which is an unknown type. Therefore, you need to specify the argument type with annotation to inform the linter about the object type.

I assumed that `ifp` is a file IO object in [`typing.IO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.io) or if it is a user-defined type, you need to specify it explicitly.

```py
from typing import IO


def peek_timestamp(ifp: IO):
    pos = ifp.tell()
    line = ifp.readline()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I understand that what you are suggesting is to define the type of the object. This works, but what I was trying to find is to have a method to see all possible implementations, like in Pycharm.  Thanks.

Comment: As I know, no linter can predict the argument type based on your code. Also, you can set multiple annotations with something like `def peek_timestamp(ifp: Union[IO, str]):` but still needs to know the possible argument types.